# How to generate assembly code (*.s) file from kernel module (*.c )?

Tags: gcc, assembly, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel

I have written one kernel module, I want to generate assembly code i.e `*.s` file.

Till now I am able to generate `.s` file from object file by using `objdump` but it's not providing me proper assembly code. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried using `-S`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `-S` option for generating an assembly code, also I would suggest to disable any optimization with `-O0` option (if you need it) , if you want to see optimized assmbly code, just add `-S`

More info about gcc options you may [find here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary)

Comment: Depends why you want to look at the asm.  If you want to see whether the compiler did a good job, you should use `-O3` (actually, use exactly the same options that you use to build a `.o`, but with `-S` instead of `-c`).  Looking at un-optimized asm output is rarely useful.  See also [how to remove noise from gcc output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output).  I like `gcc -O3 -masm=intel -fverbose-asm -S -o- | less`.  Although for kernel code, you probably need to avoid `-masm=intel` due to inline-asm assuming AT&T.